# jQuery 1.5.2 displays [object XMLDocument] for empty responses

Tags: ajax, jquery, response

I have a Url from which I can get a string

If the response string contains something, everything goes well, but (god forbid!) if the result would be an empty string like ""  jQuery 1.5.2 will display it as **[object XMLDocument]**

follow the codes plz :

```
 $.post('/Applicant/RequestedJob/IsThereActivePeriod',{},
    function(data){     
        if(data == '' ) 
        {
                //do something here!
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log(data.toString());
            // [object XMLDocument]  will be printed in console.
        }        
});
```

Perhaps I should mention that it used to work perfectly on jQuery 1.4.4
any idea?

Regards :)

Comment: is `openDialog` jquery ui dialog??

Comment: yes! but the point is somewhere else!!! ;-) it is value of the data parameter

Comment: you mean you get `[object XMLDocument]` in dialog box??

Comment: no! value of data which was supposed to be an empty string is [object XMLDocument]

Comment: means somewhere you have some header `header('content-type: xml/doc')`

Comment: I changed the code, so that people can get the question better !

Comment: what do you get when you do `console.log(data.toString());` instead of if else??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should set the expected dataType of the response in your ajax call, like this:

```
$.post('/Applicant/RequestedJob/IsThereActivePeriod',{},
    function(data){     
        if(data == '' ) 
            openDialog('/Applicant/RequestedJob/AddRequestedJobWindow','pnlRequestedJob','Request Window'); 
        else 
        {
            msgbox.show(data.toString(),'Error', msgBoxButtons.okOnly); 
            console.log(data.toString());
        }
    },
    'html'
);
```

Without this, jQuery tries to infer the response type, according [to this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json,
>   script, or html).

With no returned content, it's apparently guessing XML. By passing it 'html' as the dataType, you force jQuery to interpret the response as HTML, and store the result in plain text.

As per some of the comments, an appropriate content-type header should allow jQuery to infer that your empty string is HTML, achieving the same result without setting the expected dataType explicitly in the ajax call.

The reason you get `[object XMLDocument]` is because `data` is an XML document object, and its toString() is being called.

Comment: Excellent explanation Paul! I actually thought I would never find the answer to this one because in my case it was happening only in Firefox browser (other browsers didn't render it even though I didn't specify the dataType). Gotta love StackOverflow!!!